# argparser conditional fields depending in options

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, argparse

Currently I have a CLI tool that I'm building, and I want to give it this form similar to this.

```
usage: PROG SUBPARSER [-h] 
                 (-l {optionA,optionB,optionC} | -s TERM [-a, [-b, [-c]]])
```

What I'm doing is I have a main `cli` module, which will import all the argument_parser function from all the modules I want to expose to the user, and it dynamically adds them to the main parser as `sub parsers`

the python code bellow it's a bit from a function that adds the parser to the main parser, being parser an object from type `ArgumentParser` which could be a root parser, or a sub parser. (I do this to each module, so they have their methods exposed as CLI).

Now what I'm trying to do in this particular case, is to have a command let's say `PROG` with a first argument `SUBPARSER` that has two (possibly more) mutually exclusive sequences of arguments (without creating a new sub parsers), saying I have two functions, `search` and `list` so 
search and list could have common arguments (which will be assing to to the sub parser not the group) but there is also flags and arguments that are for use exclusively with `--list` or `--search`, in order to build commands like

```
PROG SUBARSER --list optionA -a -o -b
PROG SUBARSER --list optionA -a -o
PROG SUBARSER --list optionA -a -b
PROG SUBARSER --list optionA -a
PROG SUBARSER --list optionA

PROG SUBARSER --search TERM -a -k
PROG SUBARSER --search TERM -c
PROG SUBARSER --search TERM
```

I tried adding nested groups, with mutually exclusive and regular groups to the parser, but It doesn't allow me to (or at least I haven't found the way), to have mutually exclusive groups with multiple arguments, not just one flag or attribute.

This is what I have so far, that doesn't crash and actually runs usefully.

```
usage: PROG SUBPARSER [-h]
            [-l {all,draft,staged,publish,build,not-build} | -s SEARCH]
```

```py
def argument_parser(parser):
    """Argument parser for SUBPARSER subgroup"""
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=False)
    group.add_argument('-l','--list', 
                       choices=status_criterias,
                       help='List the content specified',
                       default='all'
                       )
    group.add_argument('-s','--search', 
                       help='Search by title from all the content')
```

Please don't mind the help strings.

Any help?

Comment: Mutually exclusive groups is a very simple test - a flat `xor`.  No subgroups or `any/and` logic.  `argument_group` is an unrelated help grouping mechanism.  Fancier testing is best done after parsing.

Comment: ok, but is there a way to add two groups that are mutually exclusive one from another?

Comment: Do you mean `xor (any(a,b,c), any(d,e,f))`?  No.

Comment: yes, I'm strugguling with the xorg part but in the end it should be something like `and(any(g, h i), xor (any(a,b,c), any(d,e,f)))`